# Add Search Button to Toolbar and Start New Activity on Click

Tags: java, android, searchview

I want to add a search magnifying class button to my toolbar. So far, I have the below code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    SearchView search = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchResultsActivity.class)));
    search.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
    return true;
}
```

However, this is not the behavior I am seeking.

I would like for the search to immediately open a new activity, with the capability for the user to type into the toolbar and perform a query right off the bat instead of having to click search again.

The reason - I want to use [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) to populate search results live. I don't want to do this on the initial `Activity`; I merely want to allow the user to click search, navigate to a new `Activity` that is linked with Algolia, and then start typing in the second `Activity` to see live search results.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: So, you just want a regular menu item then, yeah? Use a magnifying glass icon for it, and start the `Activity` in on `onOptionsItemSelected()`? I'm not really sure which part you're asking about.

Comment: I essentially want to be able to click the magnifying glass, then start a new Activity. Then, that new Activity has a Toolbar, and within the Toolbar the user is prompted to enter the search term

Comment: Right. Which part are you having an issue with? The menu item in the first `Activity`? Or the `SearchView` in the second?

Comment: Both actually, the documentation I was able to find only goes into discussion on the SearchView, which is not the behavior I am seeking

Comment: Well, you don't want a `SearchView` in the first `Activity`, then. You just need a regular menu item there, as I described above. In the second, you can put a `<SearchView>` directly inside a `<Toolbar>` in your layout, and set `iconifiedByDefault` to `false` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code

## main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/option_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search" />
```

now in your main activity do like this

## MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.option_search:
        //go to search
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

this is going to work the way you expect it

Comment: sry by mistake i actually i copied the wrong code from my code.........xD but improved it have a look